# Different names of JSON property during serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible: to have one field in class, but different names for it during serialization/deserialization in Jackson library?

For example, I have class "Coordiantes".

```
class Coordinates{
  int red;
}
```

For deserialization from JSON want to have format like this:

```
{
  "red":12
}
```

But when I will serialize object, result should be like this one:

```
{
  "r":12
}
```

I tried to implement this by applying `@JsonProperty` annotation both on getter and setter (with different values):

```
class Coordiantes{
    int red;

    @JsonProperty("r")
    public byte getRed() {
      return red;
    }

    @JsonProperty("red")
    public void setRed(byte red) {
      this.red = red;
    }
}
```

but I got an exception:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "red"

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Just tested and this works:

```
public class Coordinates {
    byte red;

    @JsonProperty("r")
    public byte getR() {
      return red;
    }

    @JsonProperty("red")
    public void setRed(byte red) {
      this.red = red;
    }
}
```

The idea is that method names should be different, so jackson parses it as different fields, not as one field.

Here is test code:

```
Coordinates c = new Coordinates();
c.setRed((byte) 5);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println("Serialization: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(c));

Coordinates r = mapper.readValue("{\"red\":25}",Coordinates.class);
System.out.println("Deserialization: " + r.getR());
```

Result:

```
Serialization: {"r":5}
Deserialization: 25
```

Comment: is the same possible with jaxb?

Comment: Will this work for `Enum`s?

Answer (score 94):

You can use `@jsonAlias` which got introduced in jackson 2.9.0

Example:

```
public class Info {
  @JsonAlias({ "red" })
  public String r;
}
```

This uses `r` during serialization, but allows `red` as an alias during deserialization. This still allows `r` to be deserialized as well, though.

Comment: The [documentation for @JsonAlias](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html)  explicitly states that it `has no effect during serialization where primary name is always used`. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz I guess @Asura means, that you can use `r` as primary name, but `red` for the `@JsonAlias`, which allows to serialize it to `r`, but adds `red` to be recognized on deserialization. Annotating it with `@JsonProperty("r")` and additionally `@JsonAlias("red")` should work fine for the given problem.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a combination of [@JsonSetter](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-json/jackson-annotations.html#jsonsetter), and [@JsonGetter](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-json/jackson-annotations.html#jsongetter) to control the deserialization, and serialization of your property, respectively. This will also allow you to keep standardized getter and setter method names that correspond to your actual field name.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;

class Coordinates {
    private int red;

    //# Used during serialization
    @JsonGetter("r")
    public int getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    //# Used during deserialization
    @JsonSetter("red")
    public void setRed(int red) {
        this.red = red;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Updated the documentation links, as the `fasterxml` GitHub pages are now returning 404.

Answer (score 17):

I would bind two different getters/setters pair to one variable:

```
class Coordinates{
    int red;

    @JsonProperty("red")
    public byte getRed() {
      return red;
    }

    public void setRed(byte red) {
      this.red = red;
    }

    @JsonProperty("r")
    public byte getR() {
      return red;
    }

    public void setR(byte red) {
      this.red = red;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case, during serialization, we will get both properties: "r" and "red", with same values.

Comment: @JsonIgnore on the methods you dont want processed will fix that issue

Comment: There are nowadays more convenient annotations: `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter`. So one can exactly set how serializer will behave.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this variant:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

//...

@JsonProperty(value = "rr") // for deserialization
@Getter(onMethod_ = {@JsonGetter(value = "r")}) // for serialization
private String rrrr;
```

with Lombok getter

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to have normal getter/setter pair. You just need to specify access mode in `@JsonProperty`

Here is unit test for that:

```
public class JsonPropertyTest {

  private static class TestJackson {

    private String color;

    @JsonProperty(value = "device_color", access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public String getColor() {
      return color;
    };

    @JsonProperty(value = "color", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public void setColor(String color) {
      this.color = color;
    }

  }

  @Test
  public void shouldParseWithAccessModeSpecified() throws Exception {
    String colorJson = "{\"color\":\"red\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TestJackson colotObject = mapper.readValue(colorJson, TestJackson.class);

    String ser = mapper.writeValueAsString(colotObject);
    System.out.println("Serialized colotObject: " + ser);
  }
}
```

I got the output as follows:

```
Serialized colotObject: {"device_color":"red"}
```

Comment: Above solution work for me . i am using Spring Rest 4 with jackson 2.9.10

Answer (score 8):

This was not what I was expecting as a solution (though it is a legitimate use case). My requirement was to allow an existing buggy client (a mobile app which already released) to use alternate names.

The solution lies in providing a separate setter method like this:

```
@JsonSetter( "r" )
public void alternateSetRed( byte red ) {
    this.red = red;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Annotating with `@JsonAlias` which got introduced with Jackson 2.9+, without mentioning `@JsonProperty` on the item to be deserialized with more than one alias(different names for a json property) works fine.

I used `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias` for package consistency with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` for my use-case.

For e.g.:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Chair {

    @JsonAlias({"woodenChair", "steelChair"})
    private String entityType;

}


@Test
public void test1() {

   String str1 = "{\"woodenChair\":\"chair made of wood\"}";
   System.out.println( mapper.readValue(str1, Chair.class));
   String str2 = "{\"steelChair\":\"chair made of steel\"}";
   System.out.println( mapper.readValue(str2, Chair.class));

}
```

just works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I know its an old question but for me I got it working when I figured out that its conflicting with Gson library so if you are using Gson then use `@SerializedName("name")` instead of `@JsonProperty("name")` hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

They must have included this as a feature, because now setting a different `@JsonProperty` for a getter and setter results in exactly what you would expect (different property name during serialization and deserialization for the same field). Jackson version 2.6.7

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to read inputs in Brazilian portuguese and generate outputs in english.

So, a workaround which worked for me was using `@JsonAlias` instead of `@JsonProperty`:

```
// pseudo-java
@Value
public class User {

   String username;

   public User(
      @JsonAlias("nome_usuario") String username) {
     // ...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use both JsonAlias and JsonProperty on the attribute.

```
data class PayoutMethodCard(
    @JsonProperty("payment_account_id")
    @JsonAlias("payout_account_id")
    val payoutAccountId: Long
)
```

In this case `paymentAccountId` can serialized from JSON either by `payment_account_id` or by `payout_account_id`, but when deserialized back to JSON JSONProperty will be used, and `payment_account_id` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a serialize class to do that:

```java
public class Symbol

{
     private String symbol;

     private String name;

     public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SymbolJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Symbol> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Symbol symbol, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();

        jgen.writeStringField("symbol", symbol.getSymbol());
         //Changed name to full_name as the field name of Json string
        jgen.writeStringField("full_name", symbol.getName());
        jgen.writeEndObject(); 
    }
}
```

```java
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(Symbol.class, new SymbolJsonSerializer());
            mapper.registerModule(module); 

            //only convert non-null field, option...
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); 

            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(symbolList);
```

Answer (score -1):

For Kotlin guys:

```kotlin
data class TestClassDTO(
    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    val username: String
)
```

You will successfull handle `{"user_name": "John"}` from POST payload in RestControllers

But when you need to serialize back with same name of @JsonProperty you can use this reflexe-approach

```kotlin
fun Any.forceSerialize(separator: String, sorted: Boolean = false): String {
    var fieldNameToAnnotatedNameMap = this.javaClass.declaredFields.map { it.name }.associateWith { fieldName ->
        val jsonFieldName =
            this::class.primaryConstructor?.parameters?.first { it.name == fieldName }?.annotations?.firstOrNull { it is JsonProperty }
        val serializedName = if (jsonFieldName != null) (jsonFieldName as JsonProperty).value else fieldName
        serializedName
    }
    if (sorted)
        fieldNameToAnnotatedNameMap = fieldNameToAnnotatedNameMap.toList().sortedBy { (_, value) -> value}.toMap()
    return fieldNameToAnnotatedNameMap.entries.joinToString(separator) { e ->
        val field = this::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == e.key }
        "${e.value}=${field.javaGetter?.invoke(this)}"
    }
}
```