# How to get key name id to Id

Tags: java

I am using ObjectMapper class to convert java bean class to json.

Output is comming in `{"memberList":[{"id":"4","member":"Saurabh K","dob":"31/12/2012"}]}`format.

I want key id as `Id(Mean Capital I)`.

My Bean Class is:-

```
class MemberClass implements Serializable{ 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
private Long Id;enter code here 
private String member; 
private Date dob; } 
MemberClass member = new MemberClass(); //some value set in to class variable ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
try {enter code here returnStr += mapper.writeValueAsString(member ); } 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Could you please format your question? It is unreadable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different names of JSON property during serialization and deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: @Tichodroma : He is new... you could have done that...

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your correctly you want to map bean property `id` to JSON property `Id`. If it is correct you can use `@JsonProperty()` annotation as following:

```
@JsonProperty("Id")
private Long id;
```

However take into consideration that this is against the widely used naming convention: property names should start with small letter.