# How to deserialize a list of objects with different names to same pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following different JSONs

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "Retailer_Relation": {...},
      "Retailer_Relation": {...},
      "Retailer_Relation": {...}
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "Retailer": {...},
      "Retailer": {...},
      "Retailer": {...}
    }
  ]
}
```

And the following class into which I deserialize the JSONs. This obviously only works for the second of the JSONs. However, I would like the JSON containing Retailer_Relation objects to work with the RetailerHolder pojo.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RetailerHolder {
    @JsonProperty("item")
    private List<Retailer> item = new ArrayList<Retailer>();

    public RetailerHolder() {

    }

    public List<Retailer> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Retailer> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }    
}
```

Is there a way to let Jackson know I also want Retailer_Relation to be deserialized into Retailer pojos?

Comment: the json text is invalid (no closing array,)

Comment: Thx, but the json is only invalid in this post. I'll update it. In my environment it is valid.

Comment: maybe this is your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564711/json-jackson-parse-different-keys-into-same-field

Comment: Is `Retailer_relation` another type or does it have the same properties as `Retailer`?

Comment: @Supahupe it has the exact same properties

Comment: Would it be an option to replace "Retailer_relation" against "Retailer" when you receive the json-string and before deserializing it by replace/replaceAll-method of String-class?

Comment: I've thought about this, but I hoped there was a less hacky solution. And I'm not sure how this affects performance for larger objects.