# use @JsonProperty bind more names with an entity class with @entity

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I want add two names on "id".
like `@JsonProperty("value")` and `@JsonProperty("id")`
How to do it?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "trainingProgramId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public class TrainingProgram {
    `private Integer id;`
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Jackson parse different keys into same field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564711/json-jackson-parse-different-keys-into-same-field)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably duplicate the value of id into another attribute with another name.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "trainingProgramId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public class TrainingProgram {
    private int id;
    private int idDupe;

    public TrainingProgram() {
        idDupe = id;
    }

    public int getIdDupe() {
        return this.idDupe;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But the better question would be: Why do you need the duplicated id value? Wouldn't it be a better design if the caller could directly use the id instead the duplicate?