# How to use different JSONProperty on Serialize & Deserialize using Jackson API?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I had a Java object "**Author**" which was then restructured to become an Ararylist of "Author". Author object was saved in DB directly as JSON below:

```
{"author":{"id":1,"recordId":0}}
```

So my earlier Java Field was :

```
private Author author = new Author();
```

and new is :

```
private List<Author> authorList;
```

Problem is how i can write my code to have Serialized object with **authorList** but need to deserialize old "**Author**" as well.

I used **@JsonProperty** to read already saved `author` data but this also saves Arraylist named "Author" which i need to name as `authorList`

```
@JsonProperty(value="author")
@JsonDeserialize(using = AuthorDeserializer.class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling around i have found solution for it.
We can use `@JsonAlias` using latest Jackson API (2.9.7)
So in my case i wanted this alias for deserialization `@JsonAlias(value={"author","authorList"})`.

[JSON Jackson parse different keys into same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564711/json-jackson-parse-different-keys-into-same-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this feature to your objectMapper:

```
DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to deserialize with the "author" property, the simplest way is just to give it the setter method it will be looking for.

For example:

```
@JsonProperty("author")
public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    setAuthorList(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(author)));
}
```

Comment: On serializing Author it should save as "authorList" and not "author" i.e. JSON shall save as "authorList":"[{data}]" and deserialize both old and new keys "author" & "authorList"

Comment: Yes. it works that way. Of course you need the authorList property too with getter and setter. Because there is only one getter: only authorList will be serialized, but because there is an other setter for author, both version will be deserialized correctly.