# Model mapper to support both camel case and snake case

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I have a Java POJO class

eg:

```
public class Student {
String name;
String rollNo;
}
```

I have rest API's that return the above bean class. Some are returning this in the snake case for example roll_no. How can I make the model mapper configured to accept both snake case and camel case serialisation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Jackson parse different keys into same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564711/json-jackson-parse-different-keys-into-same-field)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am able to parse the same in both ways using @JsonAlias

Answer (score 2):

This anotation might help you:

```
@JsonAlias({"roll_no", "rollNo", "rollno"})
String rollNo;
```

if you want more detail, follow this link [@JsonAlias anotation](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-alias-annotation.html)