# Spring rest Json issue

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I found below answered question

[Different names of JSON property during serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization)

Unfortunately this does not work when we use Spring Restful webservice. I am not sure what is cauisng the issue but it gives some Field abiguity exception.

What I want to do is Serialize and deserialize a field name with different names.

For e.g.

```
class Test {

    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("myName")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("yourName")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This does not work in Spring rest

Comment: Always provide the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set @JsonProperty for both (getter & setter). You can set for the field or setter method.

But you want different name for request and response, Create two classes like this.

```
 class StudentResponse{
   @JsonProperty(name="student_name)
   private String name;

   //getter & setter

 }

 class StudentRequest{
   @JsonProperty(name="name)
   private String name;

   //getter & setter

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Damith is right, you seem to not be able to mark both methods within the same class, however there is a way to solve this:

First off, you will have to Create a custom deserializer (or serializer, depends on your preference).

My example object:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectDeserializer.class)
public class MyObject {

private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("SomeOtherName")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Note, i mark the getter as the property with the first name. And I give the class a custom deserializer. Which looks like that:

```
public class ObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyObject> {


        @Override
        public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            MyObject object = new MyObject();

            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            JsonNode jsonNode = node.get("MyCustomSerializeName");
            object.setName(jsonNode.getTextValue());

            return object;
        }

    }
```

This class will create my custom object and get the name of the setter field description (rather than relying on the property name).

Put together, i get:

```
public class DeserializeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.setName("Hello");

        String writeValueAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        System.out.println(writeValueAsString);

        String jsonObj = "{\"MyCustomSerializeName\":\"Other Test\"}";

        MyObject readValue = mapper.readValue(jsonObj, MyObject.class);

        System.out.println(readValue.getName());

    }
}
```

And this outputs:

```
{"SomeOtherName":"Hello"}
Other Test
```

I hope that helps you.