# jackson: (de)serialization multiple different ways

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an service that talks to backend servers and front-end clients.  The backend apps are expecting JSON in one format and the front-end apps are expecting it in a different format.

If I try to using @JsonProperty I end up with a situation where either Jackson can't deserialize the data from the client or it can't serialize the data to the service because the annotations don't match.  For example: I need this to properly send my JSON to the backend servers:

```
   @JsonProperty("createDate")
   public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
      this.creationDate = creationDate;
   }
```

However, this fails to deserialize the the JSON coming from the clients.  If I remove @JsonProperty then the outcome is reserved.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?  I think I have the following options:

1. Use different models for the front end and backend.
2. Perhaps use different ObjectMapper instances?
3. Use @JsonView somehow?
4. Custom serializer?
5. JSON Schema?

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Edit:

I don't think its a duplicate because I need different names based on where the JSON is coming from or going to. Its contextually instead of being a global rename which is what it appears @JsonProperty is really good at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different names of JSON property during serialization and deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: yeah, I've read that one.  I don't think its a duplicate because I need different names based on where the JSON is coming from or going to.  Its contextually instead of being a global rename which is what it appears @JsonProperty is really good at.

Comment: Look into using custom mixin annotations for different services/clients.

Comment: @kaqqao no, from what I read he needs to serialize and de-serialize 2 different ways each.

Comment: @shmosel mixins worked great!  Do you want to add that as a response so I can mark it as the answer?