# Customize JSON response in Spring Boot to change key names

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am working with a simple Spring Boot based RestController. I am returning JSON, but I am unable to control the name of the keys generated in the response. The POJO looks like this:

```
public class SomePojo {
   @JsonProperty("name")
   private String fullName;
   @JsonProperty("name")
   public String getFullName() {
     return fullName;
   }
   public void setFullName(String fullName) {
     this.fullName = fullName;
   }
}
```

If I create a new instance as follows:

```
SomePojo sm = new SomePojo();
sm.setFullName("John Doe");
```

and return the instance in the @ResponseBody. I expect to see

```
{ "name" : "John Doe" }
```

but I am seeing

```
{ "fullName" : "John Doe" }
```

I tried using the `@JsonProperty("name")` annotation on both the property as well as its getter, but it is not working. Spring Boot version is 1.4.2. Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization/8560615#8560615) will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot might help.

Comment: set the @JsonProperty in getter and setter it will work.

Comment: @VelNaga yes, that worked! Please add this as an answer so I can select it as the right answer.

Comment: @WebUser I posted the answer. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the @JsonProperty in getter and setter it will work

Answer (score 0):

What if you change this.fullName to this.name

> public void setFullName(String fullName) {
>        this.fullName = fullName;    }

Comment: Compile error, since SomePojo does not have `name` property.