# Missing mappings with @RequestParam variables

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, request-mapping

Here's my model class:

```
public class RequestBody {

@JsonProperty("polygon")
private GeoPolygon geoPolygon;

@JsonProperty("domain_id")
private String domainId;

private String availability;

@JsonProperty("start_time")
private String startTime;

@JsonProperty("end_time")
private String endTime;

@JsonProperty("page_size")
private int pageSize;

private int offset;

//getters, setters, toString()
```

Below is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getResponse(RequestBody request){
    // process request, return response.
}
```

This is how I'm calling the API:

```
http://localhost:9876/request?availability=TEMPORARY&start_time=2017-06-06T13:24:23Z&end_time=2017-06-05T13:24:23Z&polygon={"type":"polygon","coordinates":[[[-120,10],[-30,10],[-30,60],[-120,60],[-120,10]]]}&domain_id=XYZ&page_size=10&offset=1
```

Now the issue:

All the properties are not getting mapped. Specially the ones with `@JsonProperty` annotation. These fields remain null.

I sent the same model to the `POST` request at the same endpoint and that worked completely fine. Is `@JsonProperty` not supported with `GET`?

Answer (score 3):

The `@JsonProperty` application will be taken into account during JSON serialization/deserialization. JSON deserialization occurs if the extracted content is from the request **body** (aka `@RequestBody` Spring annotation).

Your `RequestBody` (careful with name clashing) is extracted from request **parameters**. Spring will not use JSON deserialization in that case, but just call the corresponding Java Bean setters.

If you want `startTime` to be mapped with `start_time`, your setter must be:

```
public setStart_time(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}
```

Same thing for your other fields.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in answer by kagmole about difference in JSON deserialization for `@RequestBody` and `RequestParam` so you can get rid of error by doing setters on `@JsonProperty` name.

I just want to add that you should in fact have two getter / setters for your fields if you are not sure to use your POJO for `RequestBody` or for `RequestParam`.

This is highlighted in accepted answer & other answers for [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization).