# Retrofit or Jackson ObjectMapper maps "aId" property to lowercase "aid"

Tags: android, json, jackson, retrofit

I'm using `Jackson 2.9.2` and `Retrofit 2.1.0` for some `POST` operation with a `JSONArray` as `HTML-Header` parameter.

The API defines a value which is `aId`. No matter what I try, my `JSON property` is **always** converted to lowercase (`aid`).

I tested my same code with `abId`, and it works... Anyone a clue, where my configuration is wrong or which convention(?) is against this property name?

```
//ObjectMapper initialization
ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
          .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)


//the data class
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty

data class MyClass(
    @JsonProperty
    val aId: String? = null, //<-- not working
    @JsonProperty
    val abId: String? = null //working!
)

//Retrofit call 
import retrofit2.http.Body

@POST("log")
fun sendLog(@Body logs: List<MyClass>): Call<MyCall>

//JSON Result in HTML Header
[{  
  "aid":"some_value",  //should be "aId"
  "abId":"some_value"  //is correct
 }]
```

I tried with following Annotations:

- @SerializedName("aId")
- @JsonProperty("aId")
- @JsonRawValue
- @JsonAlias

Comment: Try to check [Usage of Jackson @JsonProperty annotation for kotlin data classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982148/usage-of-jackson-jsonproperty-annotation-for-kotlin-data-classes)

Comment: @MichałZiober thanks dude, that did the trick! post this as an answer to grap the bounty points

Comment: I am not sure, I should receive them for a linking to another great answer. StackOverflow does not like answers for duplicates, so, I think, some admins should mark your question as duplicated and point to linked question/answer. If you really would like to thank me, please, upvote some my answers related with `Jackson` or `JSON`, if you think they deserve it, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Michael Ziober' posted link for answer [Usage of Jackson @JsonProperty annotation for kotlin data classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982148/usage-of-jackson-jsonproperty-annotation-for-kotlin-data-classes%20Usage%20of%20Jackson%20@JsonProperty%20annotation%20for%20kotlin%20data%20classes)

Described issue is a result of `Jackson's` default bahaviour to not scan private fields. This behaviour can be change with `@JsonAutoDetect`

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
data class MyClass(
   @JsonProperty
   val aId: String? = null, 
   @JsonProperty
   val abId: String? = null 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this @get:JsonProperty("aId")

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't check the comments above. I faced the same problem in my project so I already knew the answer.