# Apply @JsonProperty on either Setter OR Getter, not both

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have this class:

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;
    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
    @JsonProperty("baaaaar")
    public setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Now if I serialize this, I would get the following result: `{"baaaaar": 0}` which seems odd to me as I only applied @JsonProperty to the Setter. I thought the Getter would keep its default behavior, that is to use the property name, and "baaaaar" would only be used for deserialisation.
Is there a solution to this, or do I have to explicitly add `@JsonProperty("bar")` to the Getter as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a single `@JsonProperty` on getter **OR** setter does set the property for both. This does allow you to rename a property for your whole application
As mentionned on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560615/11825162) you need to set both `@JsonProperty` if you want them to have different values like

```java
public class Foo {
    private int bar;

    @JsonProperty("bar") // Serialization
    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    @JsonProperty("baaaaar") // Deserialization
    public setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

***EDIT 1 :***

You might use `@JsonProperty(access = WRITE_ONLY)` following the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) and the [access properties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html#AUTO).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed that's what I found out after some research, but I thought there could potentially be another way, something like, but not exactly, JsonProperty "access" parameter.

Comment: There might be, I just checked the doc.
Check my Edit.

Comment: @AlaAbid you might use `WRITE_ONLY` for deserialization or `READ_ONLY` for serialization.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work somehow. When field itself is no longer visible in the response.

Comment: @saran3h you need to explicitly allow null values in your serializer.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507965/11825162)