# Deserialize JSON where key and value are stored separately

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a JSON structure where the key and value are stored like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "firstName",
    "value": "John"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastName",
    "value": "Smith"
  }
]
```

I would like to deserialize the array so that each key is a property name, and the appropriate value assigned.

```
public class Customer {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

I have thought of creating a custom deserializer to accept an array of customer attributes, and manually setting each property based on the attribute name. My concern is this approach could be become brittle with the addition of more properties, and is not maintainable in the long term.

Does anyone know of any Jackson annotations that I may have overlooked that would aid in this deserialization?

Comment: Write a custom `StdDeserializer` for your class which uses reflection for fields?

Comment: Some of the keys already do not match java naming conventions. Which is not a huge issue if I can get the author to confirm that all possible keys are legal identifiers. For now, let's assume that is not the case.

Comment: I suggest that this thread of comments properly should begin with an "Answer."  Go ahead and show exactly what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just annotate the properties with `@JsonProperty`

```
public class Customer {

@JsonProperty("key")
private String firstName;
@JsonProperty("value")
private String lastName;

.... 
}
```

if you want to keep the names during serialization, you should annotate the setter and getter instead of the field.

Here is an example: [Different names of JSON property during serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in a quite generic way with Jackson.

First, you will need a small Java class representing any
key/value pair (like for example `{"key":"firstName","value":"John"}`)
from your JSON input. Let's call it `Entry`.

```
public class Entry {

    private String key;
    private Object value;

    // getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Using the class above you can deserialize the JSON input
(as given in your question) to an array of `Entry` objects.

```
ObjectMpper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("example.json");
Entry[] entries = objectMapper.readValue(file, Entry[].class);
```

Then you can convert this `Entry[]` array to a `Map<String, Object>`,
and further to a `Customer` object
(using the `Customer` class as given in your question).

```
Map<String, Object> map = Arrays.stream(entries)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
Customer customer = objectMapper.convertValue(map, Customer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Jackson` will be able to deserialise a `POJO` from `JSON Object` or `Map`. You have a list of *mini-Maps* where each *mini-Map* contains exactly one property. You need to:

- Deserialise input payload to `List<Map<String, Object>>`
- Transform it to single `Map` object
- Convert to `Customer` instance

Simple example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonMiniMapsApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // read as list of maps
        List<Map<String, Object>> entries = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        });

        // collect all values to single map
        Map<Object, Object> map = entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.get("key"), e -> e.get("value")));

        // convert to POJO
        Customer customer = mapper.convertValue(map, Customer.class);

        System.out.println(customer);
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Customer {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Customer(firstName=John, lastName=Smith)
```