# JAVA : How Map JSON key value pair to different variables Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

How to map the following json to a classB object using Jackson

JSON Input

```
{"pattern":3,"graphs":4}
```

Class A

```
class ClassA{
String name;
int count;
}
```

Class B

```
class ClassB{
Set<ClassA> data;
}
```

Comment: You may be able to use [@jsonAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62339100/16653700) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a constructor in `ClassA` as follows:

```java
class ClassA {
    String name;
    int count;

    public ClassA(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

You can use `@JsonCreator` to fine tune the constructor or factory method used in the deserialization as follows:

```java
class ClassB {
    Set<ClassA> data;

    @JsonCreator
    public ClassB(Map<String, Integer> data){
        this.data = data.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> new ClassA(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```