# How to serialize request object without field name in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, serialization, jackson

I have simple REST Controller (in Kotlin) method with `@RequestBody` object.

```
@PostMappging(...)
fun postTestFunction(@RequestBody data: ExampleObject) {
    ...
}
```

Where **ExampleObject** is:

```
class ExampleObject(
    @JsonProperty("paramOne")
    val paramOne: Map<String, Int>,
    @JsonProperty("paramTwo")
    val paramTwo: String
)
```

That request can be send with next body:

```
{
    "paramOne": {
        "test": 1 // Here I can write any number of Map<String, Int>
    },
    "paramTwo": "test"
}
```

But I need another request body something like this:

```
{
    "test": 1, // I need  any number of Map<String, Int> without field name "paramOne"
    "paramTwo": "test"
}
```

What should I do to send request body with Map field (String, Int) but without field name?

Comment: Could you take the input as a String and then use ObjectMapper to convert the request into the form you want to consume? 

Also, you can try using 2 @JsonProperty, one for getter and other for setter for example:

please checkout this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560348/different-names-of-json-property-during-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: No, unfortunately client wants to send request body exactly without key field in Map value. I don't understand if I can do that with `@JsonProperty` on setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It's need to use @JsonAnySetter annotation.
I changed **ExampleObject** to:

```
class ExampleObject(
    @JsonProperty("paramTwo")
    val paramTwo: String
) {
    @JsonProperty("paramOne")
    val paramOne = MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()

    @JsonAnySetter
    fun setParamOne(key: String, value: Int) {
        paramOne[key] = value
    }
}
```

And now I can send request body the way I wanted. All fields that don't match with declared @JsonProperty annotation will be assigned to property with @JsonAnySetter method.

```
{
    "paramTwo": "data",
    "testStringOne": 1,
    "testStringTwo": 2,
    ...
}
```